# Svelte error : 'prod' is not a store with a subscribe method with shopify api

Tags: svelte, shopify-api

I am trying to make an API call to Shopify to create a variant system, however, I have an error that displays:

I don't know where this could be coming from, if you have an idea, thank you very much.

```
 <script>
    import { getProduct } from '../lib/store';
    const productId = 'a';
    const product = getProduct(productId);
    $: console.log($product);

    let quantity = 0;
    let price = 0;
    let total = 0;
    $: quantity = quantity < 1 ? 1 : quantity;

    $: options = $product.variants.edges.map((items) => {
        let list = {};
        list.id = items.node.id;
        list.color = items.node.selectedOptions[0].value;
        list.size = items.node.selectedOptions[1].value;
        list.price = items.node.priceV2.amount;
        return list;
    });

    $: console.log(options);

    let selected_color;
    let selected_size;
    let selected;
    $: selected = options.filter(function (elem) {
        return elem.size === selected_size && elem.color === selected_color;
    });

    $: if (selected_color && selected_size) {
        total = (quantity * selected[0].price).toFixed(2);
    }
    $: if (selected_color && selected_size) {
        console.log('selected variant ID : ' + selected[0].id);
        //alert('selected variant ID : '+ selected[0].id)
    }
</script>

{#await product}
    <h1>
        {$product.title}
    </h1>
    <img
        src={$product.images.edges[0].node.originalSrc}
        alt="product"
        style="width:350px;border-radius:15%;"
    />
    <br /><br />
    <h3>Color</h3>
    {#each $product.options[0].values as option}
        <label>
            <input bind:group={selected_color} selected="fa" type="radio" name={option} value={option} />
            {option}
        </label>
    {/each}
    <h3>Size</h3>
    {#each $product.options[1].values as option}
        <label>
            <input bind:group={selected_size} selected="fa" type="radio" name={option} value={option} />
            {option}
        </label>
    {/each}

    {#if selected_color}{selected_color} / {/if}
    {#if selected_size}{selected_size}{/if}
    <br /><br />
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input name="quantity" bind:value={quantity} style="width:150px;" type="number" />

    <p>
        price : $ {total}
    </p>

    {#if selected_color && selected_size}
        <p>
            Selected variant ID {selected[0].id}
        </p>
    {/if}
{/await}
```

This is my API function store.js

```
export async function getProduct(handle) {
    const query = `
  {
    productByHandle(handle: "${handle}") {
        collections(first: 1) {
        edges {
          node {
            products(first: 5) {
              edges {
                node {
                  priceRange {
                    minVariantPrice {
                      amount
                    }
                  }
                  handle
                  title
                  description
                  id
                  images(first: 5) {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        originalSrc
                        altText
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        }
      id
      title
      handle
      description
      images(first: 5) {
        edges {
          node {
            originalSrc
            altText
          }
        }
      }
      options {
        name
        values
        id
      }
      variants(first: 25) {
        edges {
          node {
            selectedOptions {
              name
              value
              
            }
            image {
              originalSrc
              altText
            }
            title
            id
            priceV2 {
              amount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`;

    const response = await ShopifyData(query);

    const product = response.data.productByHandle ? response.data.productByHandle : [];

    return product;

  
}
```

I'm trying to de it since 3 days, it's working with data .json file but not with api call, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing all instances of `$product` with `product`. In a Svelte component, starting a variable name with `$` indicates that it's a Svelte store, i.e. [an object with a subscribe method](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values). Your `getProduct` function returns a regular object, not a store, so you shouldn't need to use `$` to get the value.

Comment: Thank you i made it, now it said : Promise { <pending> }
Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined

Comment: Many thanks - I'd been scratching my head all morning over this error message. It seemed to bear no relationship whatsoever to my code. But all clear now